# find height of another div and apply math

Tags: jquery, math, height

I'm trying to find the height of an outer element called `.content` and apply that to an inner element `blockquote` minus `100px`.

```
$("blockquote").height($(".content").height());
```

This produces the current result of 600px and sets them as the same height, but I don't know how to apply math to the final output. 600px - 100px. And then apply this math result as the `.height` of the blockquote, which should now be 500px.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 5):

Just try this:

```
$("blockquote").height($(".content").height() - 100);
```

`$(".content").height()` returns only numeric value, so you can subtract 100 from that and set result height to `` `blockquote ``.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to apply the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

all versions including old versions of jquery accross all navigators

```
var _height= parseInt($(".content").height()) - 100
$("blockquote").height(height);
```